# Bitmap files added in .rc not listed in resource.h

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, bitmap, resources

I added a large number of bitmap files to my MFC project in resource view (Visual Studio). However, the resource.h file does not list any of these files. I would want them to be listed with exactly the same name as they are added in .rc bitmap list (say the name is xxx)
I want it listed as #define IDB_xxx 
If I try to click on the bitmap in the .rc list and import it, it gets listed as IDB_BITMAP1. Owing to the large number of files it is not feasible for me to manually rename them for use in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just drag the file onto the Resource View, it just open the bitmaps for editing.

So you have to Import them, then you will get them referred to as `IDB_BITMAPn`

To clean that up close the resource view then open the .rc file in *View Code* mode, find the section with the new bitmaps and find the new bitmaps like this:

```
IDB_BITMAP4             BITMAP                  "C:\\picutre1.bmp"
IDB_BITMAP5             BITMAP                  "C:\\picutre2.bmp"
IDB_BITMAP6             BITMAP                  "C:\\picutre3.bmp"
```

So now write a regex to replace the file name into the define, but also we will need to replace the numbers section in the resource.h also.

To make this easiest, make a copy of the above section.

So the first part can be done with this visual studio replace regex, which you'll want to run over the selected area

```
^:i{:b+}BITMAP{:b+}"{.*\\}{.*}.bmp"

IDB_\4\1BITMAP\2"\3\4.bmp"
```

this will make it look like this

```
IDB_picutre1             BITMAP                  "C:\\picutre1.bmp"
IDB_picutre2             BITMAP                  "C:\\picutre2.bmp"
IDB_picutre3             BITMAP                  "C:\\picutre3.bmp"
```

you then want to do a vertical selection (hold the ATL key while mousing down) over all the IDB_pictureX words then press to upper (C# keymap CTRL+SHIFT+U)

Now the to map the NEW IDB_X to the old values. We could use sed to do the work, or make a remapping file.

The latter is done by using the copy of the original .rc section, and apply this replace regex over the selected area.

```
^{:i}:b+BITMAP:b+".*\\{.*}.bmp"

#define IDB_\2\t\t\1
```

giving you this block of code looking like below:

```
#define IDB_picutre1        IDB_BITMAP4
#define IDB_picutre2        IDB_BITMAP5
#define IDB_picutre3        IDB_BITMAP6
```

which you can do the same ALT+select to change to upper case the defines, giving this code which you can place into a header file somewhere:

```
#define IDB_PICUTRE1        IDB_BITMAP4
#define IDB_PICUTRE2        IDB_BITMAP5
#define IDB_PICUTRE3        IDB_BITMAP6
```

now a more clean solution would be to build a [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) command file, and run that against your resource.h which you can do like this

```
^{:i}:b+BITMAP:b+".*\\{.*}.bmp"

s/\1/IDB_\2/
```

giving:

```
s/IDB_BITMAP4/IDB_picutre1/
s/IDB_BITMAP5/IDB_picutre2/
s/IDB_BITMAP6/IDB_picutre3/
```

copy that output into a file, and use that with the [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) -F flag